# Removing a sub package from a main package in Yocto

Tags: linux, package, embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

I want to remove the `games` pacakge from `core-image-sato` image recipe.

`core-image-sato` includes 'x11-sato' in the `IMAGE_FEATURES`.

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management x11-base x11-sato ssh-server-dropbear hwcodecs"
```

This will include `packagegroup-core-x11-sato` package.

This package has:

```
PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-base ${PN}-apps ${PN}-games"
```

I want to remove `games` from this. How can I achieve it from `local.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a `.bbappend` file of the `packagegroup-core-x11-sato.bb` file.

In your own meta, create a file: `your-meta/recipes-sato/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-x11-sato.bbappend`

This file will contain the modification you need on the packages:

```
PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-base ${PN}-apps"
```

In this way, the `PACKAGES` variable of the bbappend file will be used instead of the original `PACKAGES` variable of the recipe.